# Adding Debug DLL and Release DLL configurations in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, configurationmanager

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2010. In a previous install I had Debug DLL and Release DLL build configurations set up for C++ projects, but for the life of me I can't remember how I did it or find instructions (I vaguely remember the switches /MD and /MDd).

Can someone explain how to add 32 and 64 bit debug/release dll configurations for C++ projects?

Comment: Project + Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library setting.  Click around some more, this was designed to be discoverable.